# Trigonometric equation: $2(\sin^6 x+\cos^6 x)-3(\sin^4 x+\cos^4 x)+1=0$

Tags: trigonometry

I'm new here, but I need your help so much to solve an equation:

$$2(\sin^6 x+\cos^6 x)-3(\sin^4 x+\cos^4 x)+1=0$$

I tried a lot like making $2[(\sin^2 x)^3 + (\cos^2 x)^3$

Comment: Try to make the title about the question, not about begging for help.

Comment: Sorry but its my first time here.

Comment: Are you sure that this is the equation to solve ? It seems to lead to a severe contradiction as written.

Comment: I forgot to write +1 before =0

Comment: @dona12: then write it now. You can edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As  $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$

Taking square, $\displaystyle1=(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)^2=\sin^4x+\cos^4x+2\sin^2x\cos^2x$

$\displaystyle\implies \sin^4x+\cos^4x=1-2(\sin^2x\cos^2x)\ \ \ \ (1)$

Taking cube, $\displaystyle1=(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)^3=\sin^6x+\cos^6x+3\sin^2x\cos^2x(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)$

$\displaystyle\implies \sin^6x+\cos^6x=1-3(\sin^2x\cos^2x)\ \ \ \ (2)$

Equate the values of $\displaystyle\sin^2x\cos^2x$ from $(1),(2)$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $x^6 + y^6 = (x^2 + y^2)(x^4 - x^2y^2 + y^4)$. Then look for squares.

Also, it is not equal to zero, but to $-1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$2(\sin^6 x+\cos^6 x)-3(\sin^4 x+\cos^4 x)=0$$
$\sin x=t,\cos^2x=1-t^2$
$$2(t^6+(1-t^2)^3)-3(t^4+(1-t^2)^2)=0$$
$$2(t^6+1-3t^2+3t^4-t^6)-3(t^4+1-2t^2+t^4)=0$$
$$2(1-3t^2+3t^4)-3(2t^4+1-2t^2)=0$$
$$(2-6t^2+6t^4)-(6t^4+3-6t^2)=0$$
$$-1=0$$ CONTRADICTION